# Hard time starting car, Tried New Battery but issue has returned

Tags: honda, starting, accord

First off I have a 2009 Honda Accord EX 4 cyl. with just over 120k miles on it. A couple weeks ago I began having some issues starting the car. The car would try to turn over once or twice then stop. Once I would wait a second and try again it would go. This issue happened most often when I would try to restart my car within 15 or 20 minutes of shutting it off. In these instances I would turn the key and the lights would turn on but nothing else would happen until the second or third time trying to start the car.

Last week I took it to the garage and they tested the old battery and checked the starter and they said everything was fine including the cables. Although the battery was technically good, it was a couple years old and to rule that out I replaced the battery anyway. However a week later the issue has started to come back.

Any help in figuring this out would be much appreciated?

PS
Since I got close to 120k miles I have started having phantom issues. A month and a half ago my check engine light started flashing and I lost virtually all engine power but once I parked it at the garage and they started it up the issue was gone.

Comment: Did the shop check the alternator and charging system?  That's just as important as checking the battery, so they probably did, but you didn't mention it.

Comment: I don't know if they checked the alternator. After looking at other threads here I want to add that sometimes when I start the car there is short buzzing noise when the car turns over.

Comment: Additionally I need to change the serpentine accessory belt. It has been about 60k miles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like it needs a new starter Honda OE starters do the slow crank then click thing when they start to go. Next time it acts up see if you can smack it with something.

Your phantom issue sounds like the ECM Lost it's crankshaft variation pattern and regained it. You would need to get codes pulled to verify.

Comment: I got the starter replaced and the problem is gone. Thanks for the help.